# is there a way to actually see what are the changes in each level of git stash?

Tags: git

Assuming I did `git stash` a few times, with changes on each time, I'm able to see, using `git stash show` what are the files changed in the top of the stash stack. I can also see how many additions/deletions I had.

However, I don't know how to see the changes themselves without `git stash pop` and `git diff`

Also, how can I see the files changed (preferbaly see the whole changes, but seeing the files would also be helpful) for previous `git stash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git stash show -p <STASH>
```

If no `STASH` is given changes in the recent stash will be shown.  From `man git-stash`:

```
   show [<stash>]
       Show the changes recorded in the stash as a diff between the stashed state
       and its original parent. When no <stash> is given, shows the latest one. By
       default, the command shows the diffstat, but it will accept any format known
       to git diff (e.g., git stash show -p stash@{1} to view the second most recent
       stash in patch form). You can use stash.showStat and/or stash.showPatch
       config variables to change the default behavior.
```